# Branches/decision count in an example

Tags: testing, code-reviews

Having read SO, just found this question:

```
if (x > y)
     print (x)
else if (x < y)
     print (y)
else
     print (x,y)
```

**How many branches and decisions are there?** It mentiones there should be 3 decision and 5 branches, yet I cannot see how. For me I can only imagine 4 branches (2 Ifs with two possible results).

Original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620100/counting-decision-coverage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating this a bit more, I concluded that the statement about this code having 5 branches is incorrect.
This code definitely has only 4 branches - 4 edges to traverse. 
As IF has always two branches (one for true and one for false), with two IFs there are 4 branches in the code.
The diagram of this case (IF, ELSE IF, ELSE) is as follows. You can easily see only four branches:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
           if
          /  \    < ---- 2 branches
      false true
      else 
       if
      /  \        < ---- 2 branches
   false true
   else 
    |             < ---- 5th and final branch
```

as else part gives a decision, it is a branch too

Comment: That is why I do not understand either. There is no decision in the else part, it just a result of FALSE in the previous ELSE IF.

Comment: @user970696  See, when a true or false condition of an IF is met you do some operation in it, in the same way you do an operation even when an ELSE part is reached. As that ELSE part has some functionality, it is taken as a branch.

Comment: Exactly but when the ELSE IF evaluates to FALSE, no operation can be done and the flow continues with ELSE. What can you do between ELSE IF>FALSE and ELSE?

Comment: If the test-is-false condition and the else part count as separate branches for the second if, then why not for the first, making it a total of 6 branches?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau You have 2 decision outcomes for both IFs..but it would make 4. The last ELSE just continues from the False branch of the second IF. That is why I think 4 is enough.

Comment: @user970696: I agree with you. I would also count just 4 branches.

Comment: As far as I can understand, the branch count is not about true or false but its just about number of paths a code can take at certain decision. Considering that, the 1st decision leads to 2 paths, 2nd decision leads to another 2 paths, if these 2 are not true then the code will flow through another path as the programmer has mentioned a ELSE (which is also a decision). What I simple mean is when ELSE is used in program it internally opens up a path for the code flow. When that ELSE part is not there then you can say there are only 2 decisions and 4 branches (paths)

Comment: @VivekanandSV That is path which would be combination of outcomes. Branch is just a conditional sequence of code. You mention that the 2nd IF leads to two paths - correct, but one of them results in ELSE.

Comment: @user970696 "That is path which would be combination of outcomes." Decision/Branch analysis is possible only by the combination of outcomes right ? Thats how even the Branch Predictor [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/1934118) and [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) works

Comment: @VivekanandSV Not really. If you have an IF, you have 2 branches. IF you have another IF, you add another 2 branches. But 10 IFs would give you 1024 paths-combinations as its all possible combinations between True/False.

Comment: @user970696 Yes, when all those IFs fails. You can either give a default implementation in ELSE part or completely ignore it. What I am saying is, when you ignore then ELSE part you just go out of the IF part, but if you use ELSE then the processor has to provide a path for its execution (i.e., it needs a branch to perform the operation defined in the ELSE path)

Comment: @VivekanandSV I think we are discussing different things. Branch in a code is an outcome of a decision. When the second IF fails, the ELSE will be run as an outcome - there is no other path leading to this ELSE and it is also the only outcome of the F of the second IF.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends a bit on how you would define decision and branch. From a logical perspective I would say that there are 3 branches, because of the 3 calls to `print`. Since two `if`s are used, there are two decisions made.

On a machine level this might look different, because the compiler will generate code that might involve more branches and decisions. For example the compiler could generate code for the test `x==y`.